# When running Android JUnit tests the values of text in TextView can not be accessed by .getText().toString() causing tests to fail

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

When running Android JUnit tests the values of text in TextView can not be accessed  by .getText().toString() causing tests to fail.

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesother/203-unit-testing-with-the-junit-testing-framework

I  downloaded  the code  from the  above web-page and  ran the  unit  tests.

All unit tests  failed. The  framework did  not  return any  values from the   result.getText().toString();

Why  should this be?

CODE

// get result

```
String mathResult = result.getText().toString();
assertTrue("Add result should be 98 " + ADD_RESULT + " but was "
+ mathResult, mathResult.equals(ADD_RESULT));
}

public void testAddDecimalValues() {
sendKeys(NUMBER_5_DOT_5 + NUMBER_74 + "ENTER");

String mathResult = result.getText().toString();
assertTrue("Add result should be " + ADD_DECIMAL_RESULT + " but was "
+ mathResult, mathResult.equals(ADD_DECIMAL_RESULT));
}
```

TRACE

> ```
> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
> ```
>
> Add result should be 79.5 but was
>       at com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.test.MathValidation.testAddDecimalValues(MathValidation.java:57)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
>       at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
>       at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
>       at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same problems.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Where do you have the Object result initialized?

Add result should be 79.5 but was **""** at ...

Maybe that will help you.

Comment: How was this in any way the right answer? I have the same problem. This SampleCalc class is something that works for many people, apparently, but it's not working for me or the author.